# Como poner un campo de un select en horizontal en sql que no me duplique datos SqlServer

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select 
Paciente= HC.IdPaciente ,
Fecha_Adm = CONVERT(char(10), E.FechaAdmision, 101),
Activo = Case when  E.Estado = 'Activo' then 1 end,
Anulado = Case when E.Estado = 'Anulado' then 1 end,
Estado = Case when E.Estado = 'Anulado' then 'Solo Anulado' 
              when E.Estado = 'Activado' and E.Estado= 'Anulado'  THEN 'Activado'  else 'Activado' end
from dbo.VW_SA_EM_REP_ListadoAtencionEmergencia E
--LEFT JOIN PersonaMast         Paciente        ON  Cita.IdPaciente         =   Paciente.Persona
LEFT JOIN SS_GE_Paciente        HC              ON  E.CodigoHC = HC.CodigoHC    
where 
Year(FechaAdmision)=2018 
and Month(FechaAdmision)=08
and TipoAtencion= 'Emergencia'
and E.Sucursal = 'CEG'
group by 
HC.IdPaciente, 
CONVERT(char(10), E.FechaAdmision, 101), 
Case when E.Estado = 'Activo' then 1 end,
Case when E.Estado = 'Anulado' then 1 end,
Case when E.Estado = 'Anulado' then 'Solo Anulado' 
     when E.Estado = 'Activado' and E.Estado= 'Anulado'  THEN 'Activado'  else 'Activado' end
order by Paciente, Fecha_Adm
```

Tengo este query, de la cual el resultado me da un ejemplo si un paciente tiene como `id` 28 y su `FechaAdmsion` es igual a `01/10` pero tiene dos estados `Activo` y `Anulado`.

En base de este ejemplo me dara dos datos que uno tenga Activado y el otro Anulado pero la pregunta seria como poder hacer que este paciente que tiene dos datos poner solo uno.

[Ver aqui lo que se quiere llegar a obtener](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tyZWbwLTuG10ICY6Dabnx80yXtHQcMhhK1P6rzYrNYQ/edit?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: Te sugiero que indiques que motor de base de datos usas editando las etiquetas de tu pregunta.

Comment: Utilizo el motor de bd SQLSERVER

Comment: Podrías explicar mejor que es lo que necesitas, y ademas poner el resultado que te trae ese query y el resultado esperado.

Comment: Lo primero que viene a la mente es poner  `where e.Estado = 'Activado'`. Supongo que no te funciona, pero no logro encontrar en tu enunciado una explicación de por qué no te funcionaría. En otras palabras, no logro entender qué es exactamente lo que quieres lograr.

Comment: Buenas Tardes, ya puse un enlace para que vean como un ejemplo el resultado que me da mi query y el resultado que quisiera que me de.